# JQuery : wait any event to complete

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a following code and elements,

```
  function refreshcontent(){
              //refresh content ajax query
   }

 $("#contentpage").on("submit","#fileuploadform",function(event){

        refreshcontent();

  }); 

  <form id="fileuploadform" action="fileupload" METHOD="POST" enctype=multipart/form-data target="_blank" >
  <input type="file" name="myfile"/>
  <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
  </form>
  <div id="contentpage"> </div>
```

I want my contentpage should be refreshed when my form is completely submitted.
I am aware of setInterval function and i can use it to call ajax refresh after some time
but the problem is my filesize is not constant , it may vary and time require to submit form may vary..
also I am not using ajax to submit form (if so I could have done with success handler)

Is there any solution to solve this, Can we wait til my form is submitted?

Comment: If you're not using Ajax, your page will be reloaded anyway (and thus you don't have a possibility to run any script)

Comment: A possible workaround (not sure though) would be to execute a script on the new window when it loads: `window.opener.refreshcontent();`

Comment: Yes , now some change is there, previously it was refreshing the current window before my file is uploaded or before submit event is completed thats why my file was not getting uploaded may be event object is getting destroyed before completion, But now when i have put `window.opener.refreshcontent()` my file is uploaded but my contentpage div is not refreshed.. is this becoz the script ran in new window and has no link with current window?

Comment: I do not understand the point: why are you not using ajax to submit it ?!

Comment: Actually sir, I am uploading a word document file, and the file will be processed by server and data is extracted and should be displayed in a new window.. I tried with ajax also but I am using bootstrap modal for file upload control for which submit events are getting fired as many times I am loading the modal. I googled a lot
to find reason and solution but i couldnt get it. Sorry if I am not able to explain it clearly.. :)

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever tried with a Promise?

http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: He's not using Ajax, just a simple post in a new tab/window